# Creating video from list of images using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

### Summary

From given code, second function taking UI values and passing to first one. from log, first two lines shows command list and command string.

What's irritating me is, if I copied second line from log (dos cmd) and paste it in a cmd prompt, it works successfully and produces video correctly. but running it via gui `subprocess`, errors out.

### Task Description

Directory contains thousand of images each after few minutes of a construction project. I need to create a video from data (images) per day basis. I have successfully extracted list of images, etc, and have data.

utils.py:

```py
def framesToVideoViaCount(srcFile,outputFile,start,count,rate):
    # ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i test_%04d.png -vframes 100 -vcodec mpeg4 test.mp4
    # "C:\\Users\\lalat\\Desktop\\03008427633\\output_%04d.png"
    # ffmpeg -start_number 50 -i "C:\\Users\\lalat\\Desktop\\03008427633\\output_%04d.png" -vframes 200 -vcodec mpeg4 "C:\\Users\\lalat\\Desktop\\day1.mp4"
    command = [ 'ffmpeg',
                # '-loglevel', 'fatal',
                '-r %d' %(rate),
                '-start_number %d' %(start) ,
                '-i "%s"' %(srcFile),
                '-vframes %d' %(count),
                '-vcodec mpeg4' ]
    # command.append ('fps=%d' % (fps))
    command.append (outputFile)
    print ("COMMAND: " , command)
    print ("DOS CMD: ", ' '.join(command))
    ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
    out, err = ffmpeg.communicate()
    if(err) : print('error',err); return None;
    print (out)
```

Actual GUI function call in tk gui app:

```py
def approachByCount(self):
    tdate = datetime(year=int(self.fyear.get()), month=int(self.fmonth.get()), day=int(self.fdate.get()))
    # now = datetime.datetime.now()
    outputName = str(tdate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + ".txt"
    outputVid = str(tdate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + ".mp4"
    files = os.listdir(self.userDir)
    selected = []
    for afile in files:
        afile = os.path.join(self.userDir,afile)
        sdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(afile))
        if sdate.date() == tdate.date():
            selected.append(afile)
    # get first file name
    srcfilename = os.path.basename(selected[0])
    srcfilename,ext = srcfilename.split(".")
    filename,pad = srcfilename.split("_")
    srcfilename = os.path.join(self.userDir,filename+"_%0"+str(len(pad))+"d."+ext)
    start = int(pad)
    count = len(selected)
    utils.framesToVideoViaCount(srcfilename,outputVid,start,count,25)
```

ERROR log

```
COMMAND:  ['ffmpeg', '-r 25', '-start_number 1', '-i "C:\\Users\\lalat\\Desktop\\03008427633\\output_%04d.png"', '-vframes 382', '-vcodec mpeg4', '20190810.mp4']
DOC CMD:  ffmpeg -r 25 -start_number 1 -i "C:\Users\lalat\Desktop\03008427633\output_%04d.png" -vframes 382 -vcodec mpeg4 20190810.mp4

error b"ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers\r\n
built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017\r\n
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth\r\n
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100\r\n
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100\r\n
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100\r\n
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100\r\n
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101\r\n
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100\r\n
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100\r\n
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100\r\n
Unrecognized option 'r 25'.\r\n
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found\r\n"
```

Comment: line i was referring to (from log) in actual question..
 ffmpeg -r 25 -start_number 1 -i "C:\Users\lalat\Desktop\03008427633\output_%04d.png" -vframes 382 -vcodec mpeg4 20190810.mp4

Comment: The error message says `Unrecognized option 'r 25'` — so try fixing or removing that.

Comment: i tried that before posting here. then it start complaining about next argument 'start_number 1'. even still confusion remains same, if argument is invalid, how come same line works from cmd window directly. btw, i am using python 3.6.8

Comment: It may be because of you are not creating the `command` list correctly. Try making *each* item in it a separate string. i.e. Instead of `'-r %d' % (rate),` use `'-r',  '%d' % (rate),`, etc. Note this will need to be done for all of them that you have combined.

Comment: thankyou sir @martineau, this surely fixed issue. learned definitely something new today. i also have to wrap input in single quote, previously it was wrapped in doublequotes as well. cheers

Comment: haseeb: That's good news to hear. Peace be with you.